# Reading binary data from Kafka Topic in Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark

I need to read an encrypted message from a Kafka topic. My current code which reads strings from the topic looks like this :

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> istream1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    jssc,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(Arrays.asList(topics), kafkaParams)
                );
```

What change should I do to this code to read byte arrays from the kafka queue to make sure, the encrypted data does not get corrupted in the process of type conversion.
While I took the above code from the Spark programming guide, im not able to find this API in the KafkaUtils:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

You can see a good example of Kafka Connection [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java).

But what you want is to take a `ByteArray` from your Kafka Topic.

This Connection you need to create a `JavaPairInputDStream` like this:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
JavaPairInputDStream<String, Array[Byte]> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
    jssc,
    String.class,
    String.class,
    StringDecoder.class,
    ByteArrayDeserializer.class,
    kafkaParams,
    topicsSet
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this out. But can you tell me why we need to use a different API for this altogether and why we need to create a JavaPairInputStream.Just so I understand what I am doing.

Comment: I am not able to compile the code with the above snippet.Eclipse does not recognize the version of createDirectStream that you have listed. It sees only the version that I have used. I am using kafka010 with Spark 2.0.1.I have downloaded the spark kafka streaming jar from the maven repository.

Comment: I think maybe this could be different. But you need to set the byte deserialization

Comment: I got this working with ConsumerStategies<String, byte[]> and using a ByteDeserializer. Thanks.

Comment: Nice! Can you check the as Answered?